# In vue2.7, why original object is equal to proxy object?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue";

const raw = {};
const proxy = reactive(raw);

console.log(raw === proxy);  //true
</script>
```

In the vue3 documentation, it says false. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-proxy-vs-original-1

In vue2.7, the result is true. Please explain why this result occurs.

If the true value is correct, wouldn't it be more dangerous to change it to vue 2.7 to use vue 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

because in v2.7 vue uses api also `defineProperty` for backward compatibility with IE 11 while v3 uses `Proxy` and stops supporting IE 11

the result is reasonable you can't claim vue 3's documentation for vue 2.7

all instances of `vue@2.x` have a hydrated value referencing the `raw value` this ensures no memory waste while they are equivalent:

```js
const value = {}
const app = new Vue({ data: { value } })

console.log(app.value === value)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, does it make no sense to adapt using vue 2.7 to migrate to the vue3 version?

Can you tell me about other big differences between vue 2.7 and vue3?
Thanks!

Comment: don't worry you can safely upgrade from vue 2.7 to vue 3 if you don't use the old options api (still works in vue 3 but very clunky and heavy)
mainly ES5 support and performance is the difference between the two

Comment: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/

Comment: https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

In the vue2.x version, even if reactive is used, the original object is returned, but isProxy() returns true. Do you know why?

Comment: that's reasonable you can refer to [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information.